# unable to center image in ng2-bootstrap carousel (bootstrap 4)

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ng2-bootstrap

I am unable to center an image in the ng2-bootstrap carousel.  According to the bootstrap 4 documentation, we should only need to use the img-fluid class.

```
<img class="img-fluid" [src]="slidez.image">
```

Here is my entire div:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <carousel [interval]="myInterval" [noWrap]="noWrapSlides">
          <slide *ngFor="let slidez of slides; let index=index"
                 [active]="slidez.active">
            <img class="img-fluid" [src]="slidez.image">

            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h4>Slide {{index}}</h4>

              <p>{{slidez.text}}</p>
            </div>
          </slide>
        </carousel>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've also tried both "center-block" and "img-responsive" classes from bootstrap 3, but no dice. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out Bootstrap 4 deprecates `"text-center"`.  Instead, I used `"text-lg-center"` like so...

```
<carousel class="text-lg-center" [interval]="myInterval" [noWrap]="noWrapSlides">
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add  `center-block` class to

the image element:

```
<img class="img-fluid" [src]="slidez.image">
```

and it should work.

If that doesn't help probably you make some mess somewhere else.

Than try to reproduce on a new project using following code:

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app works!';

    public myInterval:number = 5000;
  public noWrapSlides:boolean = false;
  public slides:Array<any> = [];

  public constructor() {
    for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      this.addSlide();
    }
  }

  public addSlide():void {
    let newWidth = 600 + this.slides.length + 1;
    this.slides.push({
      image: `//placekitten.com/${newWidth}/300`,
      text: `${['More', 'Extra', 'Lots of', 'Surplus'][this.slides.length % 4]}
      ${['Cats', 'Kittys', 'Felines', 'Cutes'][this.slides.length % 4]}`
    });
  }

  public removeSlide(index:number):void {
    this.slides.splice(index, 1);
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<h1>
  {{title}}
</h1>
<alert type="success">hello</alert>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <carousel [interval]="myInterval" [noWrap]="noWrapSlides">
          <slide *ngFor="let slidez of slides; let index=index"
                 [active]="slidez.active">
            <img class="img-fluid center-block" [src]="'http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/cache/00/b7/00b7a21d94164cb8764457a894063606.jpg'">

            <div class="carousel-caption">
              <h4>Slide </h4>

              <p>SOme text</p>
            </div>
          </slide>
        </carousel>
    </div>
</div>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { AlertModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';
import { CarouselModule } from 'ng2-bootstrap/ng2-bootstrap';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    AlertModule,
    CarouselModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I'm using `angular-cli beta.19-3` and the packages for `ng2-bootstrap` :

```
"ng2-bootstrap": "^1.1.16",
"bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
```

I really hope how this will be helpful for you.

Good luck.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that.  I'm using:  "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.5"

Comment: Why you are using alpha version? Use stable one. Also related to your answer below "text-lg-center" keyword lg means how that class will be used on large screen. You have also text-sm-center, text-md-center.

Answer (score 0):

Set margin:auto to .item class.